# Finding control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, visual-studio

The following does not work:

```
var EtxtDOB = $get('<%=FormView1.FindControl("frmEditPerson").FindControl("EtxtDOB").ClientID %>');
```

How can I find this nested control in javascript?

Comment: Why not just use getElementById('<%=FormView1.FindControl("frmEditPerson").FindControl("EtxtDOB").ClientID %>');?

Also, when you go view source, does <%=FormView1.FindControl("frmEditPerson").FindControl("EtxtDOB").ClientID %> returns the correct id?

Comment: when, in the lifecycle of the page, do you try to get the clientID ? are you sure all the controls are loaded ? it looks a bit wrong to me <%= replaces the stuff youve typed with the value returned from the code at runtime, this looks wrong to me.

Comment: check the source and see what that line is emitting, im guessing there is nothing there

Answer (score 1):

I find it's a lot clearer code-wise to explicitly emit the IDs of the controls you want to access via Javascript in the page's code-behind.  Something like:

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("clientIDs", "var myControlID = '" + myControl.ClientID + "';");
```

Then you can access this anywhere in your client-side script and it's a lot cleaner:

```
var ExtODB = getElementById(myControlID);
```

If you want to get fancy create a utility function that does this for you... or create a custom attribute that automatically does this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use 'getElementById' or similar from Javascript.  If your control is named 'EtxtDOB' then this might work for you:

```
document.getElementById('EtxtDOB').setAttribute()....
```

(Not sure what the $get refers to...)

Comment: doesn't work. I believe $get and getElementById are close to the same. Although I've seen getelementID work and $get not work on occasion. I believe $get allows just server controls. i can totally be wrong though.

Comment: It won't work unless you replace 'EtxtDOB' with the *ID* of your control.  If it is a dynamically generated ID then you need to use code of the form "David" provided you in the comments to your question.

Comment: $get() is part of the ASP.NET AJAX js and defined as a shortcut to document.getElementById() - so you have to reference that .js file to use it, I think the ScriptManager also causes it to be included.